# Paytm integration iOS - linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paytm

I tried to integrate PAYTM in my project. 
The following are the steps I have done for integration.
I have dragged and dropped these files to my project:

> libPaymentsSDK_v2.0.a,
>   PaymentsSDK.h,
>   PGMerchantConfiguration.h, 
>   PGOrder.h,
>   PGServerEnvironment.h,
>   PGTransactionViewController.h

Its working fine when I run in simulator but when I try to take build in Xcode by Product-Archive it shows error:

> **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error**

I have cleaned the derived data and tried. I have all the `.m` files imported correctly in Compile sources and tried,
but still the same issue

How can I solve it?

Comment: what error displays in the output above the line saying linker command failed ...

Comment: Current Paytm sdk is not for architecture i386 so I cant build on simulator but only on devices. How did you manager to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved.
I have set Build Settings>Build Options> **Enable Bitcode** to **NO**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please add libz.tbd in binary Link Binary

Comment: Please add all c++ frameworks in your code. Similarly as you have added libz.tbd. type c++ in search bar add c++ frame work. I have faced similar issue with payu

Comment: I have faced similar issue with payu..
Did u mean paytm?

Comment: Not man have faced this in PayU. But the issue was same. When I have added conversion frame work then this issue become resoled.

Comment: Nope same issue :-(
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error

Comment: I have added around 6 c++.tbd files

Comment: Issue solved.
I have set Build Settings>Build Options> Enable bitcode to NO

Comment: Vinay Kumar
One of my collegue is integrating PayU in his project. He is facing the same linker issue. As you have already integrated PayU in your project, can you please guide.

Comment: duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
    /Users/veena/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/caretaker_user-gyjkqxwboyqkprbmbsmxcvolmwpp/Build/Intermediates/caretaker_user.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/caretaker_user.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability.o
    /Users/veena/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/caretaker_user-gyjkqxwboyqkprbmbsmxcvolmwpp/Build/Intermediates/caretaker_user.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/caretaker_user.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PUUIReachability.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: linker command failed with exit code 1